# Determine if object has dimensions

Tags: arrays, vb.net, collections

How do I figure out if a object has dimensions

```
Dim ASD as new ArrayList
ASD.add("hello")
ASD.add("World")
Dim Question as boolean = ASD.GetType.IsArray
```

Then Question will = false
But I need away to recognize that it has dimensions.
Not just for ArrayLists but for any type of collection which can store multiple objects.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
     Dim Question As Boolean = If(ASD.Count > 0, True, False)
```

Comment: What sense does the `if(..` make? `Dim q As Boolean = ASD.Count > 0` solves it perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you don't mean "dimension"? Because only arrays have dimensions. Any collection type has a count property to determine the number of elements inside.

```
    Dim asd As New ArrayList
    asd.Add("foo")
    asd.Add("bar")
    Dim elements = asd.Count
```

BTW: Dont use an Arraylist, because it's kinda outdated. Use List(of T) instead for example.